# Is there a way to get data from table #2 if it has a foreign key with table #1 and I do query for table #1

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, one called users and there is table called role_id, which gets data from second table called roles using foreign key. So role_id is an id of role but I want to get the value, which is located in roles table and print it instead of id. I don't even have a clue how to do it.
So if we look at the code:
I want to echo value of the role instead of role_id, but it is located in another table

```
$querytable = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from users WHERE role_id = '2' OR role_id = '1'");
        while($row=$querytable->fetch_assoc()):?>
         <tr><td><?php echo $row['username'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['fio'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['password'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['role_id'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['salary_fix'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['salary_percent'];?></td></tr>
        <?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: try to be more clear in you problem

Comment: what exactly do you want to display

Comment: Also show us the schema for all these related tables

Comment: now u have few answers try them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JOIN for fetch data from linked tables

like that:

```
SELECT * from users 
JOIN roles ON users.role_id = roles.id
WHERE role_id IN (1, 2)
```

and then you will have the values from the table roles for each user

check the docs for more information

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the role value instead of role_id you should use LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN roles ON users.roles_id = roles.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use a join in your query, can you provide more details about your table structure?

From what you've said I think you are looking for something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN roles on users.role_id = roles.id WHERE role_id='1' OR role_id='2'
```